# Transponder on Key Fob ineffective when below 40 degrees Fahrenheit

Tags: temperature

This webpage https://www.grupopremo.com/3dc11lp-3d-isotropic-smd-coil-for-transponder-125khz-238-720mh-13x116x315mm/485-3dc11lp-0238j.html says that my key fobs 3-Axes Transponder should work in  temperatures between -40 ºC to +85 ºC.

The last 5 times I left the key fob in my vehicle while it was in the garage I had to blow in my key fob for a good 3 - 5 minutes to get it to start the vehicle ( 2017 Dodge Journey ) at first I thought it might be the battery so i tried replacing it and also removing it completely and it did the same thing.

My personal transponder says Premo 5% X-D0240-066R3 42/16TB, Is there a button inside of the 3 sets of coils that locks in place, I cant figure out why it freezes up in 32 - 40 degree Fahrenheit temperatures?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd GUESS 1. the battery may not like the low temperatures. Can you measure the battery voltage at low temperature. Current capability may be low.  2. Just maybe a tuning capacitor may be temperature sensitive enough to shift the frequency too far.
3. Is it really the transponder? Just maybe something in the transponder warms up when the car is alerted by the door opening (if it is openable). That's a bit of a reach but just in case. || Workaround: If you must leave it in the car (sounds like a bad idea) can you provide a thermal buffer - eg water will not drop under 32F until frozen.

Comment: Most likely the battery isn't producing enough juice when it's that cold.  It's easy to get resistors, caps, inductors and semiconducors that work that low.

Comment: @Aaron It's not that capacitors "do not work" at low temperature but that change in value with temperature may detune the transponder. The car unit MAY drift the other way. That would be poor design. Which happens.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon What I mean by work, is that they are still holding their value, such that the circuit performs as advertised.  I agree, in cost sensitive designs designers may/do cheap out on caps.  If it's a part in an RF circuit, like a cap, that can influence the tuning, then it should be a C0G.

Comment: The OP said that the part is rated to -40C but it is failing at or above 0C.  What is the battery rated for?

Comment: Do not assume that the specs for one part will provide the specs for the sum of the parts ie the transponder compared to the whole remote fob.

Comment: What does the spec say about humidity?

Comment: This key fob is suppose to work "without a battery", and it does time and time again if I touch it to the start button on the dash when It's fairly warm, wouldn't that exclude the battery and the capacitors from being a problem, from my understanding capacitors run down if they dont have a power source and since the key fob dont need a power source to work, what does that leave that could fail?

Comment: That adds to the information pool :-). That makes sense of the coil arrangements. It may well be powered by inductive power transfer and have signalling implemented by NFC - near field communications. The vehicle provides a field which is rectified and used to power the transponder. | The capacitors I had in mind are for tuning. not power. || Consider my thermal buffer idea. Water will not fall below 32F until frozen to ice. If you have an insulated container of water it may take hours to days to freeze at temperatures not much below zero. ...

Comment: ... A metal surface in good thermal contact with the ware will remain at about 32F when air temperature is lower. Placing the transponder in a water buffered pocket may help.